# How do you hook into the new Pick,Pack And ship/WarehouseManagementSystem code

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I have code that worked on the old Pick pack and ship screen, the code would do a couple of changes on a QR code and then send it in to Acumatica.

With the new changes in Acumatica this is not possible any more.

What is the correct way to hook into the new (version 22) process barcode code?

Originally I could do this:

```
using WMSBase = PX.Objects.IN.WarehouseManagementSystemGraph<PX.Objects.IN.INScanReceive, PX.Objects.IN.INScanReceiveHost, PX.Objects.IN.INRegister, PX.Objects.IN.INScanReceive.Header>;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace ExtScannerCode
{
    public class INScanReceiveHostExtCustomPackage : PXGraphExtension<INScanReceive, INScanReceiveHost>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;

        #region Overrides ProcessItemBarcode
        //ProcessItemBarcode
        public delegate void ProcessItemBarcodeDelegate(string barcode);

        [PXOverride]
        public virtual void ProcessItemBarcode(string barcode, ProcessItemBarcodeDelegate baseMethod)
        {

              baseMethod?.Invoke(barcode);
                
        }
        #endregion

        #region Overrides ProcessLotSerialBarcode
        //ProcessLotSerialBarcode
        public delegate void ProcessLotSerialBarcodeDelegate(string barcode);

        [PXOverride]
        public virtual void ProcessLotSerialBarcode(string barcode, ProcessLotSerialBarcodeDelegate baseMethod)
        {

              baseMethod?.Invoke(barcode);
            
        }
        #endregion

        #region Overrides ProcessExpireDate
        //ProcessLotSerialBarcode
        public delegate void ProcessExpireDateDelegate(string barcode);

        [PXOverride]
        public virtual void ProcessExpireDate(string barcode, ProcessLotSerialBarcodeDelegate baseMethod)
        {
        
            baseMethod?.Invoke(barcode);
                           
        }
        #endregion
    }

    [PXProtectedAccess]
    public abstract class INScanReceiveHostExtProtectedAccess : PXGraphExtension<INScanReceiveHostExtCustomPackage, INScanReceive, INScanReceiveHost>
    {
        [PXProtectedAccess(typeof(INScanReceive))]
        protected abstract void ProcessItemBarcode(string barcode);

        [PXProtectedAccess(typeof(INScanReceive))]
        protected abstract void ApplyState(string state);

        [PXProtectedAccess(typeof(INScanReceive))]
        protected abstract void ProcessLotSerialBarcode(string barcode);
    }
}
```

With the new layout I am a bit lost, how would I hook into the new WarehouseManagementSystem? to process my barcodes

Comment: I have the exact same question @JvD, if you've managed to solve it in the interim, would you please share your solution? Thanks

Comment: Hey Christiaan I have got a lead to pull on 
https://community.acumatica.com/inventory-and-order-management-124/after-the-upgrade-to-acumatica-erp-2022-r1-and-later-customization-packages-used-to-customize-automated-warehouse-operations-engine-forms-may-stop-working-8025

Comment: I am still not at an answer but I think it's in that link. If you get it before me please post your answer ill do the same :)

Comment: That is a very hot lead indeed! My use case is slightly different from yours, but at it's core, we're both trying to do something before normal processing on the screen takes place. In my case I'm modifying the shipment on the pack screen when it's being loaded for packing. 

I'm working on an urgent upgrade to 22R1, and will come back to this in about a week or 2. If you haven't found a solution by then, then I'll post mine. :) 

PS. the **Handling the input without using a component** and **Alteration of the logic for a simple component** links look promising.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the private articles in the Acumatica Community site, you need to use an extension that has already been declared for each graph. For Pick Pack and Ship, the class definition would be

```
public class PickPackShipExt : PickPackShip.ScanExtension
{

}
```

From there, you would override the DecorateScanState function. There is an existing functionin the solution library, to show as an example. The code file is PX.Objects.SO\WMS\Modes\PickModes.cs.

You would inject into the state you are checking. Search for the graph you are overriding, so you can list states. For example, pick pack ship has these states:

```
   protected override IEnumerable<ScanState<PickPackShip>> CreateStates()
        {
            yield return new ShipmentState();
            yield return new LocationState();
            yield return new InventoryItemState() { AlternateType = INPrimaryAlternateType.CPN, IsForIssue = true, SuppressModuleItemStatusCheck = true };
            yield return new LotSerialState();
            yield return new ExpireDateState() { IsForIssue = true };
            yield return new ConfirmState();
            yield return new CommandOrShipmentOnlyState();
        }
```

So lets say we want to interject the lot serial number barcode reader. In this example, we want to add an X in front of what is scanned.

```
public class PickPackShipExt : PickPackShip.ScanExtension
{
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual ScanState<PickPackShip> DecorateScanState(ScanState<PickPackShip> original, Func<ScanState<PickPackShip>, ScanState<PickPackShip>> base_DecorateScanState)
    {
        var state = base_DecorateScanState(original);
                        
        //are you in pick mode?
        if (state.ModeCode == PickMode.Value)
        {
            //are you scanning lot serial information?
            if(state is LotSerialState lotSerialState)
            {
                //add some sort of validation/transoformation
                lotSerialState.Intercept.GetByBarcode.ByOverride((basis, barcode, del) =>
                {
                    //call the delegate, which just trims the barcode
                    string newBarcode = del(barcode);
                    //do something else with the barcode to transform. This example, add an X to the beginning and return
                    newBarcode = "X" + newBarcode;
                    return newBarcode;
                });
            }
        }

        return state;
    }

}
```

You can search the solution for the state, and check the functions that are called. For example, the lot serial state code is:

```
public class LotSerialState : EntityState<string>
{
    public const string Value = "LTSR";
    public class value : BqlString.Constant<value> { public value() : base(LotSerialState.Value) { } }

    public override string Code => Value;
    protected override string StatePrompt => Msg.Prompt;
    protected override bool IsStateActive() => Basis.ItemHasLotSerial;

    protected override string GetByBarcode(string barcode) => barcode.Trim();
    protected override Validation Validate(string lotSerial) => Basis.IsValid<WMSScanHeader.lotSerialNbr>(lotSerial, out string error) ? Validation.Ok : Validation.Fail(error);
    protected override void Apply(string lotSerial) => Basis.LotSerialNbr = lotSerial;
    protected override void ReportSuccess(string lotSerial) => Basis.Reporter.Info(Msg.Ready, lotSerial);
    protected override void ClearState() => Basis.LotSerialNbr = null;

    [PXLocalizable]
    public abstract class Msg
    {
        public const string Prompt = "Scan the lot/serial number.";
        public const string Ready = "The {0} lot/serial number is selected.";
        public const string NotSet = "The lot/serial number is not selected.";
    }
}
```

I hope this helps everyone get their customizations working.